# How to mock a method that is outside of a class in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I have to mock a method which is not associated with any class. Could someone help me?

It's something like this:

```
#device.rb
require_relative 'common'
class Device

  def connect_target(target)
    status = connect(target)
    return status
  end

end

#common.rb
def connect(target)
  puts "connecting to target device"
end
```

I have to write unit tests for the "connect_target" in device class
by mocking the external methods from common.rb

Comment: `allow(Device).to receive(:connect_target).and_return('something else')`?

Comment: that mocks entire connect_target method right? But I need to mock the behavor of external method i.e. "connect()"

Comment: why not mock `connect` inside `Device` rather than at a TOP_LEVEL?

Comment: There is no such thing as a method not associated with any module. There is exactly one kind of method in Ruby: instance methods of modules (or classes, which are modules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to mock a method which is not associated with any class.

There is no such thing as a method not associated with any module. There is exactly one kind of method in Ruby: instance methods of modules (or classes, which are modules).

`connect` is defined as a `private` instance method of `Object`.

You would mock it something like this:

```
allow(some_device).to receive(:connect)
```

Note that it doesn't even matter anyway, where the method is defined: there is no mention of either `Device` or `Object` here.